# How to print the element inside an object as string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to print the element in javascript that is inside an object as an string?

its a object which has all these properties.

```
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
}
```

need to create a variable "fullAddress" that points to a string using the information from the variable restaurant. for example if address was 64 johnson ave it would look like this:
64 johnson ave, Brooklyn, NY 11206.

Comment: I suggest that you use a string template in the same way you create `address` here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's low effort. the solution is a simple string concat of properties from the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
const fullAddress = `${restaurant.address}, ${restaurant.city}, ${restaurant.state} ${restaurant.zipcode}`
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use another template string:

```
const fullAddress = `${restaurant.address}, ${restaurant.city}, ${restaurant.state} ${restaurant.zipcode}`
```

Or to reduce the noise you could destructure those:

```
const { address, city, state, zipcode } = restaurant
const fullAddress = `${address}, ${city}, ${state} ${zipcode}`
```

Answer (score 1):

you can treat the object like a `class` and define a `function` that uses the `this` keyword to access its properties.

```
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1} Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
    fullAddress: function(){return `${this.address}, ${this.city}, ${this.state} ${this.zipcode}`},
};
```

and call it:

```
restaurant.fullAdress();
```

Comment: You could simplify the `fullAddress: function () { ... },` line to `fullAddress() { ... },`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const restaurant = {
    name: 'Ichiran Ramen',
    address: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1}Johnson Ave`,
    city: 'Brooklyn',
    state: 'NY',
    zipcode: '11206',
};

function getFullAdresseOf (parm){
  let temporary_string;
  temporary_string = parm.address + "  " + parm.name + ", " + parm.city + ", " + parm.state + " " + parm.zipcode;
  return temporary_string;
}

let finalString = getFullAdresseOf(restaurant);
typeof finalString ;
```

```html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65633843/how-to-print-the-element-inside-an-object-as-string-in-javascript#
```

TRY THIS FUNCTION